# Issue migrating from AFNetworking 1.3 to AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to migrate a project from AFNetworking 1.3 to AFNetworking 2.0.

In the AFNetworking 1.3 project I have this code:

```
- (void) downloadJson:(id)sender
{

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myServer/api/call?param1=string1&param2=string2"]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        // handle success

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

        NSDictionary *data = JSON;
        NSString *errorMsg = [data objectForKey:@"descriptiveErrorMessage"];
        // handle failure

    }];

    [operation start];

}
```

When the client sends a url that is not properly formatted or with bad parameters the server sends back a 400 error and includes JSON with a  “descriptiveErrorMessage”  which I read in the failure block. I use this “descriptiveErrorMessage” to determine what is wrong with the url and message the user if appropriate.

The code from the AFNetworking 2.0 project looks like this:

```
- (void)downloadJson:(id)sender
{
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myServer/api/call?param1=string1&param2=string2"]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // handle success

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        // any way to get the JSON on a 400 error?

    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

In the AFNetworking 2.0 project I don't see any way to get the JSON to read the “descriptiveErrorMessage” sent by the server. I can get the response headers from the NSHTTPURLResponse in the operation but thats as far as I can get, maybe I'm missing something.

Is there a way to get the JSON in the failure block? If not can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could try and access the `responseData` property of the passed `operation` parameter to your failure block.

Not sure that it will contain the JSON data your server sends back, but all the information should be there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @sergio, that works. I missed the responseData property. It comes as NSData, but I serialized it to JSON and was able to retrieve the message from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I found the better solution for this.
I have used 'AFHTTPRequestOperationManager'

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:@"http://localhost:3005/jsondata" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Result: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```